# excel function to highlight unique values in one column when compared with multiple columns on multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel, unique, conditional-formatting

OK i am using an excel workbook to manage the Bill of materials BOM for our products. I have several product specific sheets and a inventory sheet in one workbook.

All of the inventory is manually added to the "inventory" sheet when a new BOM is released.

I want to look for a way to search for all part numbers that only exist on the inventory sheet.

Basicly its product has been discontinued. Manually finding these part numbers is a pain.

I want to find all items that are unique to the part # column on the inventory sheet. These unique items would not exit in the part # column on any other sheet.

So I need to search the entire workbook and highlight those that are "orphaned" Then it can be easily removed from this sheet.

I can not figure out how to make a VBA function to do this or how to do this with conditional formatting.

the part numbers are can be a mixture of alpha numeric values.

I may be wanting excel to function like a relational database too much but I can dream can't I!!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Sorry I don't have the reputation to upload pictures yet. I have supplied download links to screen shots.

https://gofile.me/2rhXY/tPMTm9OF

Here is a code example: This is using the recommended VB module. This formula is not working for numeric values only.

https://gofile.me/2rhXY/fjoSA3iI

Here is the tab that the date is pulling from. It should be finding this value but is not.

Scott

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and post your code, indicating where it is failing.

Comment: Is there a part no column common to all of the *'several product specific sheets'* or do the entire worksheets need to be searched?

Comment: i did search for functions. I am very new at VBA and did not want to put dow too much infer on what did not work for me. I try to not create wasteful posts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the inventory worksheet is actually called *Inventory* and that the *'several product specific sheets'* have a common part no column this should work for you in a helper column on the inventory worksheet that can be filtered on or as a formula in a conditional formatting rule.

Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and when the VBE opens, immediately use the pull-down menus to Insert ► Module (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>). Paste the following into the new pane titled something like *Book1 - Module1 (Code)*.

```
Public Function bDiscontinued(rPART As Range, rSRCH_COL As Range) As Boolean
    Dim sPart As String, sAddress As String, ws As Long
    sPart = rPART.Value
    sAddress = rSRCH_COL.Address(0, 0)
    bDiscontinued = True
    For ws = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        With Worksheets(ws)
            If .Name <> "Inventory" Then
                If Not IsError(Application.Match(sPart, .Range(sAddress), 0)) Then
                    bDiscontinued = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next ws
End Function
```

Edit the line containing `Inventory` to suit the actual name of the worksheet that you do not want searched. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet.

The syntax is simply,

```
=bDiscontinued(<part no to look for>, <common column of part nos in other worksheets>)
```

Example: if your inventory worksheets has the part numbers in column A starting in row 2 and the part numbers on all of the other worksheets is in column B then put this formula into an unused column on row 2 of the inventory worksheet.

```
=bDiscontinued($A2, $B:$B )
```

Fill down as necessary. This new column can be filtered on for `TRUE` to show all of the discontinued part nos that can be deleted.

If simple conditional formatting highlighting rows is sufficient, the same formula could be used in a CF rule with an *Applies to:* of A2:Z9999. If the *Applies to:* was $A:$Z then change the formula to `=bDiscontinued($A1, $B:$B )`.

Comment: thanks for the reply this is working for alpha numeric part numbers. But for Part numbers that are purely numeric is is not finding them and labeling them as "true"

Comment: @scott - There's often problems when dealing with mixed text and numbers. Try changing the second line to `sPart = rPART.Text`. If that doesn't fix everything, please consider posting some redacted sample data of working and non-working part nos so we have something to go on.

Comment: added links to screen shots. Numeric values are still not working.

Comment: changing the second line to "Text" had no impact. The only trick I have found to to put a "#" symbol in the Numeric only part numbers. And them it finds them.

Answer (score 0):

Set up conditional formatting via "New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format". Assuming the range in which you want to highlight unique values is A1:A99, use the following formula:  =COUNTIF($A$1:$A$99, $A1)=1 .